# Firebase Social Login logs into last used Mail account

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook-graph-api

I have a really weird bug right now. Inside my app the user is able to login with Email/Facebook/Google. This is how the bug occurs:

When I log in via Email and log out again and then use one of the Social-Logins, it logs me into the email account that I used before??? How and why is that happening? It makes absolut no sense for me.

This is for example my `facebookLogin`- method (google-method works pretty much the same way):

```
//MARK: Facebook Login
@objc func facebookButtonTapped(){

    // disable button tap
    self.facebookButton.isEnabled = false

    let accessToken = AccessToken.current

    LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // some FB error
            Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler beim Facebook-Login", description: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }else if result?.isCancelled == true {
            // enable button tap
            self.facebookButton.isEnabled = true
        }else {
            // successfull FB-Login
            GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, name"]).start { (connection, result, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    // some FB error
                    Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler beim Facebook-Login", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                }else {
                    print(result!)
                    // check if user has account
                    guard let Info = result as? [String: Any] else { return }

                    let email = Info["email"] as? String

                    print(email!)

                    Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email!) { (methods, error) in

                        if error != nil {
                            // show error popUp
                            Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: error!.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            // no error -> check email adress

                            // enable button tap
                            self.facebookButton.isEnabled = true

                            // Email ist noch nicht registriert -> sign up
                            if methods == nil {

                                let usernameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UsernameVC") as! UserNameVC
                                usernameVC.accessToken = accessToken
                                usernameVC.signInOption = "facebook"
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(usernameVC, animated: true)

                            }
                            // Email is registered -> login
                            else {

                                // set user status to logged-in
                                UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
                                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                                // enable button tap
                                self.facebookButton.isEnabled = true

                                // transition to Home-ViewController
                                self.transitionToHome()

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tested and `printed` the `Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid` inside my `HomeViewController` and it is actually logging into the previous used Email-Account! Super weird...

If anyone can bring some light into this and help me out I am more than grateful!

If there is anything unclear and you need more info just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.. The problem was that I never actually logged the in. I just checked wether or not the user has an account. I missed to call `Auth.auth().signIn`